# Table (Shape) Insert and Resize/Reposition in Powerpoint keeps repositioning

Tags: vba, powerpoint, move, shapes

I wrote a function that copies a range/table from Excel, pastes it into a PowerPoint Slide and changes size and position. The code works as expected when executed alone, but not so when executed in a series of function calls.

In those cases the size is kept as changed but the shape/table is moved to another position. It seems the scaling is changed later on, but I don't know why. The new table can be seen at its correct position in the slide thumbnail in the left overview, but not so in the slide itself. (edit: This changes after a few second when opening the slide. Which means at some point during the code execution the shape was at the correct position.) I put a debut.print before and after the two parameters left and top to see what happens.

Left (debug.pring after insert): 48 (error!!)

Left (debug.print after change): 48.02496 (as coded/wanted)

Left (after whole macro finished): 384.025 (as later read out by immediate)

The issue seem to be with the scaling of the first two read outs. When I run the function without repositioning. The position it is inserted at is 384... and when changed to 48... it looks as expected. But in my case, what should be 384... is at the moment of insert 48. When changed to 48..., the shape is of course only moved a tiny bit. But then the whole slide seems to be rescoped and suddenly what used to be 48... is then 384..., instead of being 384... in the first place.

How is that possible? How can I counter it?
I don't even know what error to google for, since this seems so random.

Comment: This is a long shot, but by chance are you using a multi-monitor setup with the monitors at different resolutions? If so, it's caused by OLE's primitive abilities to calculate screen dimensions.

Comment: No, I am using a single screen. I am working on a notebook, without additional monitors. Calculating screen dimensions? But why would it calculate other dimensions when pasting a shape, than later on when I execute a debug.print in the immediate window? Between the two, I didn't maximize the windows or anything like it.

I kinda doubt that this has anything to do with it but for completeness: Some of the functions before are the creation of a copy of a pptx template and opening that copy for changes.